# How does subscribeOn work

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have some doubts regarding the working on the `subscribeOn` operator. I read some article regarding this.

The `observeOn` is quite easy to understand, it changes only the downstram, and change affects to all the `downstream`.

But as told in the article ***[subscribeOn can be put in any place in the stream because it affects only the time of subscription.](https://medium.com/upday-devs/rxjava-subscribeon-vs-observeon-9af518ded53a#2d09):***

To understand this , I did a samlpe and tried logging the thread at each point of time.

```
           Observable.just("Hello")
                    .map(s -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, s + " in " + Thread.currentThread());
                        return 1;
                    })
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .map(integer -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, integer + " in " + Thread.currentThread());
                        return true;
                    })
                    .map(aBoolean -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, aBoolean + " in " + Thread.currentThread());
                        return 11.0;
                    })
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                    .subscribe(aDouble -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "accept in " + Thread.currentThread());
                        Log.d(TAG, "accept: " + aDouble);
                    });
```

The result is

```
                 Hello in Thread[RxNewThreadScheduler-1,5,main]
                 1 in Thread[RxNewThreadScheduler-1,5,main]
                 true in Thread[RxNewThreadScheduler-1,5,main]
                 accept in Thread[RxNewThreadScheduler-1,5,main]
                 accept: 11.0
```

Here twice I'm applying `subscribeOn`, but everytime the first added one seem to be applied throughout the stream.

Can anyone please explain in simple words how does it actually work, since I'm a beginner and hard to digest this!

Thanks in advance

Comment: if I remember it right, `subscribeOn` describes the beginning, i.e which thread will start the emissions. only first one will be used if there are multiple declarations.

Comment: the `subscribeOn` closest to the observable wins. the second is ignored

Comment: SubscribeOn is will be used to create the observable. So creation is only possible from on thread, so only subscribeOn is possible for one observable.

Answer (score 2):

`subscribeOn`: If you have multiple `subscribeOn` then the first one takes effect. If you want to change the Scheduler on the stream after making a `subscribeOn`, then take a look at `observeOn`

`observeOn`: It changes the Scheduler going downstream.

For example:

```
just("Some String") // Computation
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()) // it changes scheduler to computation beginning from source to observer.
  .map(str -> str.length()) // Computation
  .observeOn(Schedulers.io) //change the scheduler from here till the observer
  .map(length -> 2 * length) // io
  .subscribe(number -> Log.d("", "Number " + number));// io
```